# Boot into windows directly (not windows boot manager)/Editing the windows BCD from linux?

Tags: windows, boot, multi-boot, bcd

I accidentally deleted the windows 7 option from the windows boot manager using bcdedit, and now can't boot into it. Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to create a Windows 7 boot media (of the same Service Pack level as your
installation), then do Startup Repair while booting from it.
Or you could use instead a system repair disc (if you have created one).

Using the boot media, boot to the *System Recovery Options* screen and
select the *Startup Repair* option.

For more information see the article:
[How to Perform a Startup Repair in Windows 7](https://www.lifewire.com/how-to-perform-a-startup-repair-in-windows-7-2626170).

Comment: I can't make the repair disc now as I no longer have acess to the machine, and it came pre-installed with windows 7, I don't have the install media. I feel like I'm in a pinch.

Comment: Try to get it from the [Windows USB/DVD Download Tool](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=56485). I suggest first creating a backup image of the disk with a tool such as [AOMEI Backupper Freeware](https://www.aomeitech.com/aomei-backupper.html).